# Strange behavior of the ZeroMQ PUB/SUB pattern with TCP as transport layer

Tags: windows, zeromq

In order to design our API/messages, I've made some preliminary tests with our data:

Protobuf V3 Message:

```
message TcpGraphes {
    uint32 flowId                   = 1;
    repeated uint64 curTcpWinSizeUl = 2; // max 3600 elements
    repeated uint64 curTcpWinSizeDl = 3; // max 3600 elements
    repeated uint64 retransUl       = 4; // max 3600 elements
    repeated uint64 retransDl       = 5; // max 3600 elements
    repeated uint32 rtt             = 6; // max 3600 elements
}
```

Message build as multipart message in order to add the filter functionality for the client

Tested with 10 python clients: 5 running on the same PC (localhost), 5 running on an external PC.
Protocol used was TCP. About **200 messages** were sent every second.

Results:

1. Local client are working: they get every messages
2. Remote clients are missing some messages (throughput seems to be limited by the server to 1Mbit/s per client)

**Server code (C++):**

```
// zeroMQ init
zmq_ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
zmq_pub_sock = zmq_socket(zmq_ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
zmq_bind(zmq_pub_sock, "tcp://*:5559");
```

every second, about 200 messages are sent in a loop:

```
std::string serStrg;
tcpG.SerializeToString(&serStrg);
// first part identifier: [flowId]tcpAnalysis.TcpGraphes
std::stringstream id;
id << It->second->first << tcpG.GetTypeName();
zmq_send(zmq_pub_sock, id.str().c_str(), id.str().length(), ZMQ_SNDMORE);
zmq_send(zmq_pub_sock, serStrg.c_str(), serStrg.length(), 0);
```

**Client code (python):**

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
sub.connect('tcp://x.x.x.x:5559')
print ("Waiting for data...")
while True:
    message = sub.recv() # first part (filter part, eg:"134tcpAnalysis.TcpGraphes")
    print ("Got some data:",message)
    message = sub.recv() # second part (protobuf bin)
```

We have looked at the PCAP and the server don't use the full bandwidth available, I can add some new subscribers, remove some existing ones, every remote subscriber gets "only" 1Mbit/s.

I've tested an Iperf3 TCP connection between the two PCs and I reach 60Mbit/s.

The PC who runs the python clients has about 30% CPU last.
I've minimized the console where the clients are running in order to avoid the printout but it has no effect.

Is it a normal behavior for the TCP transport layer (PUB/SUB pattern) ? Does it means I should use the EPGM protocol ?

**Config:**

- windows xp for the server
- windows 7 for the python remote clients
- zmq version 4.0.4 used

Comment: Clicked [ +1 ] for providing version details, ( would be worth re-**edit the post** so as to contain a **complete MCVE**-code, both  on the server-side and proper multipart message handling on the client side. This original code snippets violate the StackOverflow standard of a **M**inimum-**C**omplete-**V**erifiable-**E**xample of code, that runs and self-demonstrates the presented ill-shaped behaviour for consultation with Community members.

Comment: just added the code who send the messages (in a loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A performance motivated interest ?

Ok, let's first use the resources a bit more adequately :

```
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// zeroMQ init
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

zmq_ctx = zmq_ctx_new();

int aRetCODE = zmq_ctx_set( zmq_ctx, ZMQ_IO_THREADS, 10 );

assert( 0 == aRetCODE );

zmq_pub_sock = zmq_socket(  zmq_ctx, ZMQ_PUB );

    aRetCODE = zmq_setsockopt( zmq_pub_sock, ZMQ_AFFINITY, 1023 );
    //                                                     ^^^^
    //                                                     ||||
    //                                 (:::::::::::)-------++++
    // >>> print ( "[{0: >16b}]".format( 2**10 - 1 ) ).replace( " ", "." )
    // [......1111111111]
    //        ||||||||||
    //        |||||||||+---- IO-thread 0
    //        ||||||||+----- IO-thread 1
    //        |......+------ IO-thread 2
    //        ::             :         :
    //        |+------------ IO-thread 8
    //        +------------- IO-thread 9
    //
    // API-defined AFFINITY-mapping
```

Non-windows platforms with a more recent API can touch also scheduler details and tweak O/S-side priorities even better.

---

### Networking ?

Ok, let's first use the resources a bit more adequately :

```
    aRetCODE = zmq_setsockopt( zmq_pub_sock, ZMQ_TOS, <_a_HIGH_PRIORITY_ToS#_> );
```

---

### Converting the whole infrastructure into **`epgm://`** ?

Well, if one wishes to experiment and gets warranted resources for doing that E2E.